# Storing the time stamp for when each index has been set in a BitSet?

Tags: java, bitset

Is there a way that on top of the BitSet I can store a time stamp for when each entry has been set in a java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a List of the timestamps. Or a Map, or an array, depending on your requirements.

You can subclass `BitSet` to make it easier to use with existing code.

Note: adding a timestamp could increase memory usage by a factory of 65 or more.  This will work best for smaller BitSets.

Comment: Your Note is the problem I'm having this will be used to dedup a data stream in storm and will have a lot of records and I have to implement a way for each bit I set to clear its self after a configurable amount of time. So the difficulties I'm having is all this has to be memory efficient as well as very fast

Comment: @Coder86 you will have to trade off cpu for memory. You can retain lists of bits to reset to minimise memory usage but this works best if there is a limited number of resets pending.

Comment: just not sure whats the best implementation originally I was using a HashMap holding onto the hashed values that I used for the index of bitset being set as well as the timestamp of when it was set.  Then when the same duplicate is discovered again I would check the map and see if its already end of its time to live but I want to implement something that will clear the index of the bitset on its own.  Something like a continuous bloom filter.

Comment: @Coder86 Would using an LRU cache like LinkedHashMap help?

Comment: yea I was thinking of using something like that but I guess I wanted to come up with a clever way to solve this issue.  There is a implementation of what I need but its in Ruby.  I was going to try to learn enough Ruby so that I can implement it in java but instead decided to email the developer and see if he can explain his logic to me.